# Can't make the CurvedBend component from openmodelica work properly

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I'm trying to use the component `CurvedBend` from the `Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.Bends.CurvedBend standard library`. I don't get how to specify its geometry . I tried using `curvedBend(redeclare package Medium = Medium, geometry(d_hyd = 12.8e-3, R_0 = 0.0695, delta = 1.7, K = 0.025))` but I get the following error message :[image]

I didn't get any problem using the `edgedBend` component. I found someone with a similar problem ( here is the link : https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5906#comment:5). From what I understand its an issue between the inputs order from the geometry of the curved bend and the geometry of the IN_con of the pressure loss function. Is it an issue from openmodelica which can be resolved or am I doing something wrong ?

Best regards,
Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like the same OpenModelica issue as reported in https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5906#comment:5 (that you linked to).

Running a similar example in Dymola (Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatingSystem with a CurvedBend between heater and pipe using those parameters) does not show that problem.

The best work-around I can find is to make an (incomplete) copy of MSL and re-order the components in the different geometry-records to be in the same order.